# cleveref package and gather environment

Tags: cleveref, gather

I use the `cleveref` to cross-reference my equations and I have no problems with the `equation` and `align` environments. However, when using the `gather` environment, the cross-reference reads: "Section x.y.z" instead of "Equation x.a".

How to ensure that `cleveref` refers to `gather` as equations?

**MWE**

Note that I have an appendix wher I changed the "section" printed by 'cleveref' to "appendix".

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[class=book]{tudapub}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Bold math symbols

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % For capitalized ref
\usepackage{appendix} % Needed to trigger clevref names change for appendix sections


\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\crefalias{section}{appendix}} % To rename sections in clevref when entering appendices
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{\crefalias{section}{section}} % To rename sections back in clevref when leaving appendices


\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{My chapter}
    
    
    \section{My section}

    This is an equation in the 'equation' environment:
    \begin{equation}
    \label{Eq_equation}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
    
    This is an equation in the 'align' environment:
    \begin{align}
    \label{Eq_align}
    a &= b
    \nonumber \\
    c &= d
    \end{align}
    
    This is an equation in the 'gather' environment:
    \begin{gather}
    \label{Eq_gather}
    a = b
    \nonumber \\
    c = d
    \end{gather}
    
    I can use the package 'cleveref' with 'equation' and 'align: these are cross-references to \Cref{Eq_equation} and \Cref{Eq_align}.
    
    But it does not work with 'gather': this is a cross-reference to \Cref*{Eq_gather}.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post a minimal (non)working complete code?

Comment: Using the simplest of MWEs I have no issues with `cleveref` and `gather` so please provide code as Bernard mentions.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, sorry it took a while to get a MWE from my whole thesis. It is now added to the question.

Comment: you have used the label on an unnumbered line, what do you want it to refer to?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To the equation 1.2 composed of the two lines. This is currently the behaviour I am looking for with the 'align' environment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle While it worked with 'align' that was the reason for the problem with 'gater'. Thank you! If you add your comment as an answer, I could select it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gather` each line is numbered separately and so can have a separate label, in this case the `\label` is in an unnumbered like due to `\nonumber` so it references the currently active label which is typically the most recent section heading.

The same ought to be true of `align` but the processing of `align` is more involved and if it picks up something more useful in that case, that is by accident not design.